# Are these the correct ages of the characters of Devil May Cry?

Tags: timeline, devil-may-cry

I've been investigating different interviews and info that the games and other media like anime and manga provide and I got this timeline regarding characters' ages. Does this seem correct?

### EVA’s MURDER (1982)

- Dante’s Age: 8
- Lady’s Age: 6
- Trish’s Age: 0
- Lucia’s Age: 0
- Nero’s Age: 0
- Patty’s Age: 0

### DEVIL MAY CRY 3 (1993)

- Dante’s Age: 19
- Lady’s Age: 17
- Trish’s Age: 0
- Lucia’s Age: 9
- Nero’s Age: 0
- Patty’s Age: 0

### DEVIL MAY CRY 1 (2002)

- Dante’s Age: 28
- Lady’s Age: 26
- Trish’s Age: 0
- Lucia’s Age: 18
- Nero’s Age: 9
- Patty’s Age: 3

### DEVIL MAY CRY: The Animated Series (2007)

- Dante’s Age: 33
- Lady’s Age: 31
- Trish’s Age: 5
- Lucia’s Age: 23
- Nero’s Age: 14
- Patty’s Age: 8

### DEVIL MAY CRY 2 (2009)

- Dante’s Age: 35
- Lady’s Age: 33
- Trish’s Age: 7
- Lucia’s Age: 25
- Nero’s Age: 16
- Patty’s Age: 10

### DEVIL MAY CRY 4 (2012)

- Dante’s Age: 38
- Lady’s Age: 36
- Trish’s Age: 10
- Lucia’s Age: 28
- Nero’s Age: 19
- Patty’s Age: 13

### DEVIL MAY CRY 5 (2017)

- Dante’s Age: 43
- Lady’s Age: 41
- Trish’s Age: 15
- Lucia’s Age: 33
- Nero’s Age: 24
- Patty’s Age: 18

Comment: Can you provide us the sources you're working from? That might help us determine authenticity.

Comment: It would be good if this noted that the dates given are the estimated/presumed internal dates, and not the media release dates.  Also, who would have thought that SF&F would join the list of SE sites needing a proper markdown table implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This info is completely wrong, and now I know why people keep citing the wrong info to me in debates, this site is one of the first results google search gives.

- DMC 3 Manga - Dante/Vergil 18, Lady 17
- DMC3 Game - Dante/Vergil 19, Lady 18
- DMC 1 - Dante/Vergil 28
- DMC Anime - Dante/Vergil 29, Lady 28, Patty 8
- DMC 4 - Dante/Vergil 34, Nero 19, Lady 33
- DMC 2 - Has pretty much been retconned to have happened just before
  DMC5, so no actual age is given, but before the retconning there was an accompanying novel with the game where Dante was celebrating his 42nd birthday, but that novel has officially been deemed NON canon by Itsuno himself
- DMC 5 - Dante/Vergil 39, Nero 24, Lady 38, Patty 18

39-24=15, -another 9 months of pregnancy Vergil was roughly 14/15 when Nero was conceived, and as for the mother, it was supposedly a prostitute, given, it might have been the same woman we saw in the DMC4 cutscene, but it might have been her after she had already given birth and abandoned Nero and due to quilt stopped whoring herself and became pious, her looking at Vergil in that cutscene might have been her recognizing him from their fling.

Your sources are the games themselves where they have year dropped all the major events. Absolutely nowhere is it stated that Dante was 34 in the anime, but it was confirmed by the anime itself that it takes place 1 year after what is referred to as "The Mallet Island Incident", thus he is in fact 29.
And if you want to to use the dubbed line of Trish saying "I've been telling you years to stop eating that (referring to Dante's pizza)", then no, that was confirmed to be a dubbing error and was never in the original script.

Comment: The OP was merely asking if their figures were correct, not asserting that they were. If anyone chose to take said figures as gospel based on that question, the blame lies with them, not the OP. Also, while the figures in your answer may be correct, you haven't provided any quotes or citations to demonstrate that. This answer would be much improved if you edited to include relevant quotes and citations.

Comment: [Please be kind to other users of the site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct)